# Convert mp3 to wav on Android

Tags: android, mp3, wav, audio-converter

There seem to be a lot of questions regarding the inverse wav to mp3 conversion, but none to go the other way. My situation is that I can use steganography to embed data in wav files. I can convert these to ogg and back (the steganography is format independent, and can survive format conversion). What I want to do now is build in AudioBoo integration. Uploading to AudioBoo is not a problem, retrieving the files in mp3 format is not a problem, but converting those mp3 files back to wav to perform the steg. extraction is. Does anyone know where I should start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html). It should run on Android. Beware, some of the calls are `synchronized`. If this doesn't work, tweak the source code or extract the converter modules from the entire source, since all you need is the mp3 to wav converter, not the mp3 player.