# Fast conversion from mp3 to WAV on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, mp3, wav

I am trying to **convert a mp3 file into WAVE format** in my Android application. This operation should take little time, as the application is social, and it is not acceptable for the user to wait for too long.

So here is where I am :

- I have already tried to use JLayer (proposed in a similar question [Convert mp3 to wav on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289620/convert-mp3-to-wav-on-android)), but the conversion is too slow: it takes about 40 seconds for a 2 minutes mp3 file.
- Concerning the library LAME (as in [Lame4Android](https://github.com/intervigilium/Lame4Android)), I also tried it (with Android NDK) but the result is still too slow (15s to 10s).
- I came across another library: [JUCE](http://www.juce.com/), but it is too vast, and including the entire library in the project in order to do that simple conversion seems a bit... excessive. And I am also afraid it will slow the application.

So what I am currently looking for is a C/C++ library to use in order to do that.
Do you know any *fast* libraries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the license will work for you (GPLv2), but have you considered [libmad](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad)?

As I understand it, there's not a NDK build available for download, but [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=231) is a page describing how to make one yourself...

Another option is [libmpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/index.shtml), which is LGPLv2.1.  The same blog [has an article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=446) describing how to use it in Android.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am going to look into it.